# Google API getPlace from autocomplete return undefined when firing manually

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, google-places-api

I want to be able to return the data from `autocomplete.getPlace()` when firing this event manually.

Basically, I have one function that get's user location in `Lat/Lng` and after that I want to get users getPlace(), because there is more useful data, such as place_id, photos (the most wanted), reference, etc.

So far, I can do almost everything, I can even fire the event manually, but it return `undefined`. This is the code I have so far:

```
var latLng = response; //Comes from another function
geocoder.geocode({'location': latLng}, function(results, status) {
    if (status === 'OK') {
        if (results[1]) {
            var fullAddress = results[0].formatted_address;

            var input = document.createElement("input");
                input.setAttribute("value", fullAddress);

            var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);

            google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function () {
                var thisPlace = autocomplete.getPlace();
                console.log(thisPlace);
            });

            google.maps.event.trigger(autocomplete, 'place_changed');
        }
    }
});
```

Everything here is working, but the return from `autocomplete.getPlace()` is `undefined`.

If run the same function, but from a native autocomplete element, the return is correct.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want the JavaScript equivalent to [Android Place Picker](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/placepicker). There is no such widget in the [Places library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places). Consider [filing a feature request](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/entry?template=Places%20API%20-%20Feature%20Request).

Your current approach seems to go along these lines:

1. Reverse geocode user latlng to the nearest address.
2. Get Places at that address.

Using `geocoder.geocode()` for step 1 is OK, but you need to be careful about which results you take in: if the first result is a bus stop, it's address won't be useful.

You'd be better off with [Radar Search](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#radar_search_requests), to search for the nearest places to the original Lat/Lng input. This also avoids issues that may come from reverse geocoding snapping the user location to a not-so-near address. Then you'll need to issue a number of [Details](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_details) requests to get the names (and other details) of the nearest N places.

Using Autocomplete for step 2 is not going to work well. Autocomplete for an address with multiple Places at it will rarely list all of them.

Besides: do not fire `place_changed` manually, that's not how it works.

The `place_changed` event is fired by the [Autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Autocomplete) class only after making a [PlaceResult](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#PlaceResult) available. If the user has selected a place out of Autocomplete predictions, this requires a call to the Places Details service, to retrieve the details you actually want to get.

> This event is fired when a PlaceResult is made available for a Place the user has selected.
>   If the user enters the name of a Place that was not suggested by the control and presses the Enter key, or if a Place detail request fails, a place_changed event will be fired that contains the user input in the name property, with no other properties defined.

If you fire the `place_changed` manually, there is no `PlaceResult` ready for you, which is why `autocomplete.getPlace()` will only return `undefined`.

Comment: Based on your link references I ended up getting the results I wanted but with another method. Instead of firing manually the autocomplete event, I'm using `PlacesService` to make a new search. after that, the main objective was achieved and I'm able to get the information I need. Thanks